# Syncfusion ToolStripEx inside ribbon control - How to align it to right

Tags: winforms, syncfusion

I've a windows form containing a ribbon control with tabs, and some ToolStripEx controls. What I want is align some ToolStripEx controls to right of the windows form.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In our current implementation, ToolStripEx has been arranged one by one based on previous ToolStripEx position, therefore we do not have support to arrange it on the right side of the ToolStripTabItem.

So can you share the purpose of arranging the items on the right side of the window and also the items which you would like to place it on the right side? Based on your update, we will proceed further on this.

Regards,

Keerthana J